# LyX: Move or remove bottommost toolbar

Tags: lyx, tools

In LyX there's the bottommost toolbar that displays various bits of useful information.

In order to save space on my screen, can I remove this toolbar?

[image]

Or if I can't, can I maybe move it next to another toolbar, e.g. like this:

[image]

(By the way, is there a name for this toolbar?)

Comment: To save space, nothing better than F11 (View → Fullscreen) and F11 again if you need to return to the menu/toolbars.

Answer (score 1):

This region is intended to give you feedback from the Lyx-GUI about latest actions, hints etc. Here e.g. I selected some text:

[image: example]

I don't think, you can remove or move it, at lest it's not evident to me from the Preferences. So here are some things you could do:

- ignore it / live with it
- follow [Fran's advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11604/fran) using full screen
- shift your Lyx window close enough to your screens bottom, so it's "hidden"
- find out where it's handled in source code, modify and compile Lyx as a program